# Java - reading values Chars in one array list and converting them into strings in another

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a program that converts a users input into Morse code.
To do this I have two text files, one storing the Morse alphabet and another storing the English alphabet.

I'm trying to read the the chars in the users input, one by one, and compare them to the chars in a character arraylist to find the appropriate index. I then just append the translation variable with the value at that index in the Morse array list. (They are organized so that this works).

Yet for some reason, I am recieveing an IndexOutOfBoundsException when it compares the char to the normals arraylist.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MorseCode
{
    public static String translate(String input) throws IOException
    {
        //Convert input to lowercase
        input.toLowerCase();
        //Create final statement
        String translation = "";

        //Store values
        ArrayList<String> morse = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Character> normals = new ArrayList<Character>();

        //Scan and read file
        Scanner morseFile = new Scanner(new File("morsecode.txt"));
        Scanner normalsFile = new Scanner(new File("normals.txt"));
        while (morseFile.hasNext())
        {
            morse.add(morseFile.next());
        }
        while (normalsFile.hasNext())
        {
            normals.add(normalsFile.next().charAt(0));
        }

        //Begin checking for chars and converting
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length() + 1; i++)
        {
            //Set current char
            char currentChar = input.charAt(i);

            //Begin comparing chars
            for (int b = 0; b <= normals.size() + 1; b++)
            {
                //If char equals x
                if (currentChar == normals.get(b))
                {
                    //Append translation
                    translation += morse.get(b);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Nothing
                }
            }
        }
        return translation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post (by using [edit]) your entire exception, including full stack trace, and identify program lines it refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Remove + 1 in the condition , `b <= normals.size() + 1`, inside inner for loop. `b <= normals.size()` is enough

Comment: I had simply added the plus one to see if to removed the out of bounds exception, so it doesn't affect it.